# Ubuntu phone, Back to images overview button missing?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I've bought the new ubuntu phone last week,
still figuring out how to accomplish one specific thing.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch the gallery app

   - list with all pictures appears
2. Click on one of the pictures

   - The image is loaded in fullscreen

I can't go back to the screen with all the pictures.
Any thoughts how that can be accomplished ?

Best regards,
Oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch somewhere on the screen and the back option will appear in the upper left corner.

Comment: @OlegVidenov: Welcome to AskUbuntu! 
As you're new: Don't thank anyone on this site, but accept their answer as valid if it helped you... That is the best way of thanking people as their reputation will go up! ;-)